# what is commit=0 for ext4? does mdadm not support it?

Tags: filesystems, software-raid, ext4, options, mdadm

I see this in my dmesg log

```
EXT4-fs (md1): re-mounted. Opts: commit=0
EXT4-fs (md2): re-mounted. Opts: commit=0
EXT4-fs (md3): re-mounted. Opts: commit=0
```

I think that means that dealloc is disabled? does mdadm not support dealloc?

Comment: It appears that for some reason when a system is using ext4 on a RAID set, it wants to remount the set with the "commit=0" option set. I am currently seeing the same thing happen with 3ware hardware RAID. Like the original poster, I have no idea why this is happening. I am running two different OS's on the same hardware. Mandriva 2010.2 is NOT remounting with the commit option set, Mageia 1 is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mdadm supports dealloc.

`commit=sec` is the time, the filesystem syncs its data and metadata. Setting this to 0 has the same effect as using the default value 5.

So I don't get the link between mdadm and commit=0 in your question?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why the system is remounting my FS's like this... I'm certainly not setting it to anything, and before I moved to mdadm raid I never saw this. 5 is something like what ext3 uses where I think the default for ext4 is something like 600

Comment: I asked this question the LKML and the answer I got was that something though KDE/Hal was remounting the drives for some reason.

Comment: To xenoterracide: Default 600 sec.? Here http://Kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt is something different: "...
The default value is 5 seconds.
... Setting it to 0 will have the same effect as leaving it at the default (5 seconds).
..."

Answer (score 1):

RTFM mount(8)

```
   commit=nrsec
          Sync  all  data  and  metadata  every nrsec seconds. The default
          value is 5 seconds. Zero means default.
```

Very short.

New drives unload heads. Would then need base on commit size and run the risk of loosing 10 min of work to save wear and tear on disc.